# Angle (degree) symbol with siunitx under XeLaTeX and mathspec

Tags: xetex, siunitx, mathspec

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\ang{30}, \SI{20}{\celsius}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with XeLaTex, I get:

[image: Missing degree]

The angle misses the degree symbol. With the package `fontspec` instead of `mathspec` it works fine (but I need `mathspec`).

Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you tried \textdegree from textcomp package?

Comment: With recent version of `siunitx`  (v3.1.8, last revised 2022-10-04.) your MWE gives desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{math-degree=\mbox{\textdegree},text-degree=\textdegree}
\sisetup{math-celsius=\mbox{\textdegree}C,text-celsius=\textdegree C}

\begin{document}
\ang{30}, \SI{20}{\celsius}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the right Unicode character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  text-degree=°,
  math-degree=\textup{°},
  text-celsius=℃,
  math-celsius=\textup{℃},
}

\begin{document}
\ang{30}, \SI{20}{\celsius}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `siunitx` version 3 it's even simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\degreeCelsius}{\textup{℃}}

\begin{document}

\ang{30}, \SI{20}{\degreeCelsius}

\end{document}
```

Comment: FYI: Checking today, I found that `siunitx` has removed those options.  The error messages are like "Option "text-degree" has been removed in this (siunitx)  release."  I use texlive 2021, constantly updated via `tlmgr`.

Comment: @Ryo I added the code for siunitx version 3